# Scalable UDP server

Tags: c++, performance, networking, udp

I need to make a Server that will listen and answer to UDP packets,
It will listen 10 ports.

The packets are very small, no more than 20 bytes.
Each packet will modify or search into a huge hash-table.

But it have to process 15k packets per second.

I can develop in c, c++ or qt.

There is any special guidelines that need to meet this requirements ? What is the basic design to use ? Is threading a need ?

Comment: 15k/minute is 250/second.  This should be an almost trivial workload (assuming you're going to be working on a modern desktop/server platform), so I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Oli, sorry i made a typo, is 15k/second.

Comment: Ok, that sounds somewhat less trivial!

Comment: Any reason for using 10 different ports? just wanted to know..

Comment: which platforms are you targeting?

Comment: @Len: From the mention of C++/QT, I assumed Linux. If it's Windows, there's additional advice I could give.

Comment: QT's cross platform isn't it?

Comment: Are you building a web server cache? Have you seen memcached?

Comment: Should be Linux or Windows, no problem.

Comment: QT is a GUI library. Are you sure that's what you meant?

Comment: @MarkR, Qt is not just a Gui library. Is have very good auxiliar librarys and is possible to do a Command line software in Qt.

Comment: Ok, I stand corrected, it seems that Qt has some facilities other than a GUI.

Answer (score 5):

For this sort of performance, I would consider a `select()`-based "commutator loop":

- Open the listening UDP sockets
- Call `select()` to determine sockets with readable data
- For each readable socket, read bytes (non-blocking read)
- When you get a complete packet, process (and write, as needed)

You can build a simple table that dispatches on `select()` results.

This approach will give you the best possible performance, because it's as close as you can get to the operating system calls, with minimal overhead.  It runs as a single process, minimizing context switching and getting the best cache locality.

Next, if you find things are CPU bound, consider ways to use multiple CPU cores with multiple threads or processes.  For example, can you have each processor handling N of your 10 sockets, with the hash table in shared memory.

Finally, I'd be careful about using a lot of threads (e.g. a large worker pool of threads, etc.).  At extreme performance levels, thread overhead can get significant.

Comment: Good advice. A thread pool that feeds from a queue of pending packets might be the way to go.

Comment: Actually poll() and platform-specific system calls like epoll() and kqueue are much more efficient than select().

Comment: @ldx:  Not necessarily -- it depends.  On many systems poll() and select() are very similar (sometimes one being implemented as a thin layer on another). epoll() and kqueue will excel when you have a large number of file descriptors.  Here, he's got only 10 with a very high packet rate:  they're going to be readable MOST of the time.

Comment: It is unlikely that the scalability of poll / epoll etc, is required with a UDP server, because it only needs a single socket. In principle, it could be implemented using blocking reads.

Answer (score 4):

[Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview.html) is the perfect choice for a scalable UDP server. Using it has several advantages over programming to the [socket APIs](http://linux.die.net/man/2/socket) directly:

1. The library is mature and proven, implementing your own `select`, `poll,` or `epoll` reactor will most likely encounter bugs.
2. Using an `int` to represent all socket types lacks type safety, `asio` uses types such as `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket` and `boost::asio::ip::udp::socket`.
3. It scales to [thousands of concurrent connections](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/async.html) by promoting asynchronous design patterns instead of a thread per connection.
4. Adding [multithreading support](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html) for enhanced scalability is trivial.

Comment: What the advantage of Boost.Asio over a direct Api call ?